# javascript: when looping again through array, I want object property to reset

Tags: javascript, angularjs, loops, object

I am trying to make an object, where the keys are number of years and value is amount of money

```
vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost = {"2016":0,"2017":0,"2018":0,"2019":0} //year(key):amount(value)
```

I have an input field in the view,  that lets me make new amount and everytime I add different addLocalCostContributor and it will check if the condition matches,the amount will be added to the year.

```
function addLocalCostContributor(localCost, year) {
        localCost.contributors.push({});

          for(var i=0; i < localCost.contributors.length;i++ ) {
            if(angular.isDefined(localCost.contributors[i].contributor) && localCost.contributors[i].contributor.name ==='Agriterra') {
              var amount = parseInt(localCost.contributors[i].amount);
              vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = parseInt(vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] || 0) + amount;
            }
          }
    }

vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost = {};//ths is intiliased in the top of angular controller
```

Problem is that whenever new amount is added and conditions are met, the amount increments but it starts the loop all over again. For example I add firstAmount, it gives me {'2016' : firstAmount}, but when I add newAmount and submit it starts loop again and it gives {'2016': firstAmount + firstAmount + newAmount}, while all I want is firstAmount + newAmount. If i can reset the  `vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year]`  everytime I submit (and the function loops to increment the property) I will get the right answer. 
[image: looping problem when logged]
I can't think clearly how and where to reset this property, if some one can see from different eyes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try resetting the amount for that year before the `for` loop runs.

```
function addLocalCostContributor(localCost, year) {
    localCost.contributors.push({});

    vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = 0; // <= added this line

    for (var i = 0; i < localCost.contributors.length; i++) {
        if (angular.isDefined(localCost.contributors[i].contributor) 
        && localCost.contributors[i].contributor.name === 'Agriterra') {
            var amount = parseInt(localCost.contributors[i].amount);
            vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] = parseInt(vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost[year] || 0) + amount;
        }
    }
}

vm.argiterraYearlyLocalCost = {};
```

Comment: @HarisKhan sure, no problem :)